# Select N percentage of rows by account

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to select a percent of a population by the account number, but I need that percentage to be evenly distributed by department.

For example:

I have 100 rows for account 12345. I need 10 percent broken down by department.

```
dept  count 
1     2 
2     2 
3     2
4     2 
5     2
```

The percentage can change at any given time. Do anyone have any good ideas for me to start with? I tried using the tablesample function, but it look like it was limited for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Do you need 10% of each department, or 10% of the entire population divided evenly by department?  Also do you need a random sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have enough rows, you can use window functions.  To get a 10% sample evenly distributed with this trick:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by account order by seqnum_within_account) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by account, dept order by (select null)) as seqnum_within_account,
                   count(*) over (partition by account) as cnt
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum * 10 <= cnt;
```

What is this doing?  The innermost `select` is assign a sequential number to each department within each account.  The next is assigning a sequence number within each account, so it is evenly distributed across departments.  So, if there are n departments, the first n values are from different departments, as are the next n and so on (assuming there are enough rows).

The final `where` takes a 10% sample.

Note:  You can add a `where account = ???` to the innermost subquery, if you want the information only for one account.

Comment: I believe that generating sequence number for each account should have an order by seqnum_within_account

Answer (score 0):

Use Row_Number() window function

```
;with cte as (
  select *
  , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by dept order by AccountNo) AS Rn
  , count(AccountNo) over (partition by dept order by dept) AS Cnt
  from #tt
)
select *
from cte 
where Rn<=(1.0*Cnt)/10
```